# Backup Maven dependencies to repository

Tags: maven

I am frequently using maven artifacts as dependencies from external repositories which go (permanently) offline surprisingly often. I'd like to save all dependencies a given project has and save them in a local repository - just like using `maven deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=...` for a single project. This repository should then be usable like any other maven repo when put on an HTTP server.

I tried using `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true`, but it does not create files like `maven-metadata.xml` or copy `.pom` files.

I do not want to use any repository managers like Artifactory, I just have a static file server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `mvn dependency:go-offline` what you want?

Comment: How would that allow me to save the dependencies in a repository? As far as I understand that command, it would just save the dependencies in the `.m2` local repo, but not a custom one to be uploaded.

Comment: This is the problem that Maven repository managers like Nexus, Artifactory and Archiva are designed to solve. I would highly recommend using Nexus. Very lightweight, I use it on my machine all the time to support off-line development.

Comment: Anything that runs on the JVM is not lightweight in comparison to nginx (JVM has a high memory overhead). The core problem is, in my opinion, very easy to solve: Find all those dependencies and run the same code `deploy` uses for each of them.

Comment: @user3224302 that command will save the dependencies into any repo you specify it to (with `maven.repo.local` configuration)

Comment: How about mvn install?

Comment: Same as @MarkO'Connor, but +1 on Artifactory. Unzip and run on your local machine as a service. Transparent, efficient, problem solved.